# AWS S3 bucket access issue with switching role

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My login to AWS console is MFA & for that I am using Google Authenticator.
I have S3 DEV bucket and to access that DEV bucket, I have to switch role and after switching i can access DEV bucket.

I need help how to achieve same in python with boto3.

There are many csv file that I need to open in dataframe and without that resolving access, I cannot proceed.

I tried configuring AWS credentials & config and using that in my python code but didn't helped.

AWS document is not clear about how to do switching role while using & doing in python.

```
import boto3
import s3fs
import pandas as pd
import boto.s3.connection

access_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
secret_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# bucketName = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

Expected result should be to access that bucket after switching role in python code along with MFA.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is a bad for security to put credentials in your program code. It is better to store them in a configuration file. You can do this by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command.

Once the credentials are stored this way, any AWS SDK (eg boto3) will automatically retrieve the credentials without having to reference them in code.

See: [Configuring the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)

There is an additional capability with the configuration file, that **allows you to store a role that you wish to assume**. This can be done by specifying a profile with the Role ARN:

```
# In ~/.aws/credentials:
[development]
aws_access_key_id=foo
aws_access_key_id=bar

# In ~/.aws/config
[profile crossaccount]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam:...
source_profile=development
```

The `source_profile` points to the profile that contains credentials that will be used to make the `AssumeRole()` call, and `role_arn` specifies the Role to assume.

See: [Assume Role Provider](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#assume-role-provider)

Finally, you can tell boto3 to use that particular profile for credentials:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='crossaccount')
# Any clients created from this session will use credentials
# from the [crossaccount] section of ~/.aws/credentials.
dev_s3_client = session.client('s3')
```

An alternative to all the above (which boto3 does for you) is to call [`assume_role()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role) in your code, then use the temporary credentials that are returned to define a new `session` that you can use to connect to a service. However, the above method using profiles is a lot easier.